# Insert an item in javascript object at particular position

Tags: javascript

I have an object in javascript whose structure is like this.

```
{
  Comment : "Test" 
  CurrentWt : "0" 
  Label : "O" 
  MaxWt : "1680"
  Aft: "0" 
  lat : "0"
  lon: "0" 
  Button : "false"
  position : "0"
}
```

I want to add an element after button and before position. How to do it?

Comment: Object keys are unordered.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the order of the object?

Comment: Why is the order important?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: This object will be converted to XML so it is important to maintain the order

Comment: XML nodes are likewise unordered

Comment: @Nikhil: Why is the order of the *XML* important?  Also, if the order is important, then you should be explicitly defining that order when building that XML.  You're trying to rely on things which don't make the guarantees you're assuming.

Comment: You cannot change this order.. You can handle this while you read your converted XML data..

Comment: After your edit: You can't, objects don't have any specific order, use array if you need an order. The order you see when logging an object is an order provided by the logger, when you iterate the method using an object iteration method, you might get a different order, which might even vary depending by implementation.

Comment: "*This object will be converted to XML so it is important to maintain the order*" - err.. no, it isn't. There's NO ORDER, so you can't maintain something that's not there. Also, why is it relevant in which order the elements are in XML, if there's no hierarchy whatsoever?

Answer (score -1):

if position matters so much to you then i'd suggest you to use arrays.. use two arrays. One for the keys and one for the values.

eg:

```js
let arr1 = ['Comment','CurrentWt ','Label','MaxWt','Aft','lat','lon','Button','position']
let arr2 = ['Test', '0','o','1680'.......]
```

And then all youve to do is find the index of the required element in arr1. i.e 'Button' and add element to its next index.. for both the arrays

Comment: Why not rather to use an array of objects ..?

Comment: I assume you're talking about key value pair as an object and pushing them in array?  But again to get the index, you'd have to check the object,.. wont it be complicated process?

Comment: You can't push key value pairs to an array, you put them in an object, and push that object into an array. It's not complex to iterate, I'd find more complex to keep the two separate arrays in the correct order if you need to sort the keys or add members between indices.

Comment: @Teemu please let me know what approach you were talking about.

Comment: ?? `[{Comment: 'Test'}, {CurrentWt: '0'}, ... , {position: '0'}]` an array of objects. It looks like I read your previous comment a bit poorly, yes, we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Teemu, This looks like better approach. But, now how do i get the index of the object in that array where 'CurrentWt' key is present? Is there any easier direct way to do that?

Comment: Remembering we know the exact order now, `arr[1].CurrentWt` ... usually it' better to use a helper function. Also, this is not for large data, if you need to access the data using both, index and key ...